# How to distinguish if message is from ReSharper or Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, resharper, visual-studio-extensions

The text is in Italian, but the literal translation would be: the member wasn't fount in the data context ClustersManagementTabDesignViewModel.

[image]

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClustersManagementTabAdapterView"
             xmlns:clusters="clr-namespace:Clusters"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=clusters:ClustersManagementTabDesignViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White">

    <telerik:RadGridView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Nome Cluster" DataMemberBinding="{Binding ClusterName}"  Width="auto"/>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not from ReSharper - it does not support any other languages except English. Easy way to check if an inspection is from ReSharper is to press "Ctrl-Alt-Shift-8" to disable all ReSharper's analysis in the opened file. Don't forget to press the combination again to enable the analysis.